# Odoo Managing Database Page

Tags: odoo-9, openerp-8, erp

I am trying to remove the other html/xml elements for the page where you can restore or delete database. Does anyone know the location from the local files so i can edit the file?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post your attempt so far. This website is about helping people with specific problems. If you can show you've made some effort you're more likely to get help.

Comment: I am about edit something. I'm not asking for codes sir. Just the file path so i can do the coding. I've been searching the whole local files.

Comment: Btw it's solved now. thanks!

Comment: If you solved it then write answer. So other User can get benefit of it. Or You can delete your question. Because mentioned issue is not a generic or more likely to reproduce same.

Comment: Okaayyy. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 9.0-20161004\server\openerp\addons\web\views\database_manager.html

File path on local servers.